# displayImage and loadImage not caching the same file?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, picasso

Following is my code in my class:

```
@Override
public void displayImageAsync(ImageView iv, MyImageLoadingListener listener)
{
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(getImageUrl(), iv, listener);
}

@Override
public void loadImageAsync()
{
    ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(getImageUrl(), new MyImageLoadingListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoaded(boolean completed, View view, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            if (completed)
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ImageMatchLoadedEvent(getThis(), bitmap));
        }
    });
}
```

after calling `displayImageAsync` (and succcessfully displaying the image), it seems, that `loadImageAsync` does not use the bitmap from the `displayImageAsync` call... Is that intended? After calling `loadImageAsync` once, the bitmap is cached and everything works as suppopsed...

Am I missing something? As you can see, both calls use exactly the same url...

Answer (score 1):

Use picasso which is easy to use..

```
 ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_prod_pic);

 Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view); //url is image url

 //you can resize image if you want

 /* Picasso.with(context) .load(url) .resize(50, 50) .centerCrop() .into(view) */
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/
[image]